# GET /swagger-ui.html fails with HTTP 206

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I'm using spring-boot 1.5.0 RELEASE with swagger 2.6.1. I've added `@EnableSwagger2` annotation on my spring boot application and defined a `@Bean` of type Docket. I've not used `@EnableWebMvc` annotation anywhere. I've excluded swagger-ui.html from security. When i call /v2/api-docs, i get the correct response JSON. But when i call /swagger-ui.html, it fails with HTTP 206. In chrome, it fails with `Failed - No file`. In console it shows the following error - `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type multipart/byteranges: "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html"`.

Comment: Did you add springfox-swagger-ui dependency ?

Comment: Yes, I have swagger-ui dependency in my pom with the same version (2.6.1)